# make multiple rows one row with additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that looks like

```
Customer_id     Order_id   Action    Time_Stamp
abc             123         placed     8/1/2012 10:00AM
abc             123         processed  8/1/2012 10:30AM
abc             123         shipped    8/1/2012 11:00AM

xyz             456         recieved   8/1/12 12:00PM
```

what i am trying to get is

```
Customer ID     Order_id   Placed             Processed           Shipped            recieved
abc              123       8/1/2012 10:00Am    8/1/2012 10:30AM   8/1/2012 11:00AM   null
xyz              456       null                null               null               8/1/2012 12:00PM
```

i know the max number of columns i would need (the number of actions in other words) if that makes the query easier.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want real help, please post the CREATE statement for the table and a few Insert Statements for the data. It is hard to write working queries looking at the data.

Comment: What if there are two rows for processed, e.g. if an order gets returned and then re-shipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this type of query.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT Customer_id, Order_id, Action, Time_Stamp
    FROM yourTable
) x
PIVOT
(
   max(Time_Stamp)
   for action in ([Placed], [Processed], [Shipped], [received])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14416/3)

The above query works great if you know the values of the columns you want to create. But if you do not, then you can use a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(action) 
                    from test
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
      = 'SELECT Customer_id, Order_id,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select Customer_id, Order_id, Action, Time_Stamp
            from test
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            max(Time_Stamp)
             for action in(' + @cols + ')
         ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14416/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are expected a fix set of states, and not multiple states per order, something like this may work for you:

```
SELECT customer_id, order_id
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN action = 'placed' THEN time_stamp ELSE NULL END) AS placed
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN action = 'processed' THEN time_stamp ELSE NULL END) AS processed
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN action = 'shipped' THEN time_stamp ELSE NULL END) AS shipped
      ,MIN(CASE WHEN action = 'received' THEN time_stamp ELSE NULL END) AS received
  FROM activity
  GROUP BY customer_id, order_id
```